# Compare two lists & print elements which are repeating in second list

Tags: java

I have searched but couldn't find specific to what I was looking for.

I have a duplicate list got from Main List.
E.G.:

```
duplicateSet { D16A, D2243A, D2235A} 

xConnectors { D16A, xxx, xxxx, xxxx, D16A, xxxx , D2243A ,xxxx, D2243A, xxxx, D2235A, xxxx, xxxx, D2235A}
```

I wrote this code

```
Set duplicateConnectors = new HashSet();
                for(String s : duplicateSet)
                {       
                    for(IXConnector xCon : xConnectors)
                    {
                        if(s.equals(xCon.getAttribute("Name")))
                        {
                            duplicateConnectors.add(xCon);
                            vReporter.report(getDefaultSeverity(), "Connector {0} is duplicate", xCon);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

The o/p I get is

```
Connector D16A is duplicate
Connector D16A is duplicate
Connector D2243A is duplicate
Connector D2243A is duplicate
```

But I need the above o/p in one single line.

```
Connectors D16A and D16A are duplicates.
Connectors D2243A and D2243A are duplicates.
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: `But I need the above o/p in one single line.` And how do you think you can achieve that? Did you even try anything?

Comment: Could you make an ArrayList of strings, and add "Connector {a} and {a} are duplicates.", then print off every other value in the list?

Comment: The duplicate set is a set of Strings. But the xConnectors is not list of strings. It has objects. And I need to print out the objects. And I'm not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code runs in quadratic time i.e. O(n^2) and that is not a very scalable solution, because as your input will grow your running time will grow quadratically.

You should utilize a Hash Set to your advantage here, a hash set is a set that does not allow duplicates and items are hashed into an indexed array hence you receive constant time performance for insertion and contains. You now have one loop to check whether a connector name is found in the hashset earlier, if it is then it is a duplicate, this check is also constant time. So your whole algorithm becomes linear.

```
 Set<String> dupes = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String s : duplicateSet)
            dupes.add(s);

        for(IXConnector xCon : xConnectors)
        {
            String name = xCon.getAttribute("Name");
            if(dupes.contains(name))
                vReporter.report(getDefaultSeverity(), "Connectors {0} and {0} are duplicates.", xCon);
        }
```

If you want to print the message only once, you can change the HashSet to a HashMap and use a boolean as a value to represent whether or not you have printed a message yet.

```
Map<String, Boolean> dupes = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        for(String s : duplicateSet)
            dupes.put(s, false);

        for(IXConnector xCon : xConnectors)
        {
            String name = xCon.getAttribute("Name");
            if(dupes.containsKey(name) && dupes.get(name) == false)
            {
                vReporter.report(getDefaultSeverity(), "Connectors {0} and {0} are duplicates.", xCon);
                dupes.put(name, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not quite sure how the vReporter.report works, and I wasn't sure if you could do that.

Comment: @SaviourSelf me neither, but that's the least of his worries. He needs to use HashSets/HashMaps to his advantage here. That way he doesn't get duplicate messages and still stays in linear time.